# Linking to a page with an iframe in it

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to link to a page that contains an iframe. Let's say the page has the link `http://www.some_page.com/products`. The iframe is a product list loaded from another source like `http://products.some_other_domain.com/seller_id=3984y329`.

When I click one of the products in the list a detail page on that product is show. This means that my browser is still on the page `http://www.some_page.com/products`, however the content of the iframe is now `http://products.some_other_domain.com/seller_id=3984y329&product_id=34534`.

Now I can of cause just link directly to `http://products.some_other_domain.com/seller_id=3984y329&product_id=34534`, however that would not render the page `http://www.some_page.com/products` which is the one I really wanted to link to.

Is there any way to "fake" this or do something, so that I can manipulate the content of that iframe to show what I want, when linking to the page?

Comment: No. Not unless you control that main `http://www.some_page.com/products` page.

Comment: I don't unfortunately :-(

Comment: I wonder if it would be easy to e.g. write a piece of JS that the owner of `http://www.some_page.com/products`could embed in the head of his page, that could look for a param like `http://www.some_page.com/products?send_iframe_to=http%3A%2F%2Fproducts.some_other_domain.com%2Fseller_id%3D3984y329%26product_id%3D34534` and then change the link in the iframe accordingly using JS?

Answer (score 0):

You could try 'fetch' that page using [get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and manipulate the source but there's some work involved...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: using ajax you could fetch the html hosted on http://www.some_page.com/products, manipulate this html by i.e. adding your own javascript and showing this page on your own website. That way you DO control this page. But it has a lot of risks.. some client browsers prevent cross domain scripting etc..